# Difference between IE script and notification settings

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

What are the differences among these IE settings:
`Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)`
`Disable script debugging (Other)`
`Display a notification about every script error`

1. If I turn on all of the three settings what type of errors would be
   disabled and what type of errors would be displayed as 
   notifications?
2. I noticed that by default script debugging (the first two settings)
       is disabled in the IE. Is it recommended to test the web application
       with script debugging enabled?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: This question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you can't vote to close questions with bounties. You'd be better off asking this over at http://superuser.com or on Microsoft's own forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on the IE team. These settings have changed meaning a bit recently, so I'll try to clarify:

**Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer)**

This setting only has impact on Visual Studio versions prior to 2013. When enabled (unchecked), Visual Studio can attach its debugger to already running instances of IE. When disabled (checked), Visual Studio can only debug IE if Visual Studio is the one to launch the browser. In other words, already running instances of IE cannot be debugged by older versions of VS if this is checked.

**Disable script debugging (Other)**

When enabled (unchecked), this setting allows Visual Studio (all versions) to debug web content in applications that host the WebBrowser control. Checking this box prevents VS from debugging these applications.

**Display a notification about every script error**

This controls whether a dialog box that comes up as a script error is hit. The dialog gives you the opportunity to launch a system debugger (e.g. Visual Studio) at the time of the error.

**Recommended Configuration**

You only need to consider changing these settings if you use an older version of Visual Studio (pre-2013).  In fact, changing these settings could negatively affect the performance of your page's JavaScript as this can cause the engine to not use JIT compilation.

If you use the built-in F12 debugging tools or newer versions of Visual Studio, the debug console replaces the need for the script error notification as errors are logged there. The other two settings do not affect F12 or new versions of VS's ability to debug script.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I have noticed that Enabling the script debugging throws some extra script error messages which are not thrown with "Display a notification ..." set to on. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 4):

- Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)

> the above will turn script debugging just for browser "internet
>   explorer"

- Disable script debugging (Other)

> the above will turn script debugging on for all applications that host
>   the WebBrowser control (Outlook for example).

- Display a notification about every script error

> means that although the script errors will continue to occur, you
>   will be notified about them with an popup box or in console box

Comment: It's not only about `WebBrowser` hosts, but about any other [Active Script Hosts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589(v=vs.94).aspx).