# Activate error message in mshta.exe

Tags: error-handling, hta

I'm trying to make an HTA on a very old Windows XP with IE8. I made an error in the program (which I've corrected since) and I accidentally checked the box "do not show this kind of message again" and now if I make an error it doesn't tell me. How do I reactivate error messages?

Comment: Post your HTA Code !

Comment: Use [Internet Options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795254/1169519) via Control Panel or IE.

Comment: @Hackoo It has nothing to do with the code, it does that for all HTAs. Besides I've already corrected alll the errors (at least I think so). My code is a 8MB .js file and a 80MB .hta file (so you might understand why I neeed automaitc error check).

Comment: @Teemu I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Try again, there's nothing else. mshta.exe doesn't have its own error message system, everything comes from IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As before ppl said Internet Explorer should do the trick as that is the engine you are using.
Go to Internet Explorer (11) Settings, Advanced Tab, Reset Internet Explorer.
Apply and test your HTA.
Just had the same problem and I just solved it :)

[image]